# Controle de conteúdo - Java Sax

Tags: java, xml

[Java - Sax Parser] Boa tarde.
Se alguém puder me ajudar eu ficarei grato.

Preciso montar uma aplicação que funciona da seguinte maneira:
Caso ele encontre a tag "`classname`", e esta possuir um atributo "`type`" com o valor "`M`" ou "`V`", então seta o nome da tag `classname`.

Setando a tag `classname`, ele verifica as suas tags filhas, e caso possua a tag filha "`parameter`" e esta possua o atributo name, então seta este atributo do `parameter`. Há ainda uma outra situação, onde caso contenha uma tag filha chamada "`mapping`" então não seta nenhum valor. Esta parte está correta e funcionando.

Porém eu preciso agora fazer um controle de conteúdo, ou seja, antes de setar o valor de `classname` ele deve verificar se este valor já existe, caso não exista, seta normalmente conforme acima, já se caso existir, aí verificar os valores de `parameter`, e caso esses valores também já existam, aí não seta nada, mas caso possua algum `parameter` diferente, aí seta apenas este `parameter` diferente no `classname` já existente.

Arquivo XML de exemplo:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<prozessdef>
    <beschreibung></beschreibung>
    <kunde></kunde>
    <aktion>
        <parameter name="pPROZESS_ID"/>
        <classname type="M">common.Filecache/AAA</classname>
    </aktion>
    <aktion>
        <parameter name="pPROZESS_ID"/>
        <classname type="M">common.Filecache/BBB</classname>
    </aktion>
    <aktion>
        <parameter name="pPROZESS_ID"/>
        <classname type="V">common.Filecache/AAA</classname>
    </aktion>
</prozessdef>
```

Classe `SaxWFReader`:

```java
public class SaxWFReader extends DefaultHandler{

    /** Buffer que guarda as informações quando um texto é encontrado */
    private StringBuffer tempValue = new StringBuffer(50); 

    /** Lista que possui as tags do arquivo XML */
    private ArrayList<Aktion> aktion = new ArrayList<Aktion>();

    public ArrayList<Aktion> getAktion() {
        return aktion;
    }

    /** variáveis temporárias, apenas para coletar as informações do XML */
    private Parameter parameterTemp;
    private Classname classTemp;
    private Aktion    aktionTemp;

    //contantes que representam as tags do arquivo XML
    private final String NO_AKTION          = "aktion";
    private final String NO_CLASSNAME       = "classname";
    private final String ATT_CLASSNAME_TYPE = "type";
    private final String NO_PARAMETER       = "parameter";
    private final String NO_MAPPING         = "mapping";

    //variáveis para controle de conteúdo
    boolean mappingOpen   = false;
    boolean mappingExist  = false;
    boolean typeClassName = false;
    boolean parameterOpen = false;
    boolean aktionOpen    = false;

    /**
     * Construtor que irá varrer uma pasta, lendo todos os aquivos terminandos
     * com .xml. Cada vez que encontrar um arquivo, irá fazer o parse do arquivo.
     *  
     * Constutor que inicializa os objetos necessários para fazer o parse
     * do arquivo xml
     * @throws ParserConfigurationException
     * @throws SAXException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void parse() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {

        File dir = new File("/home/pal/Área de Trabalho/teste");
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser parser = spf.newSAXParser();
        if (dir.isDirectory()){
            String[] files = dir.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                if(files[i].endsWith(".xml")){
                    parser.parse(files[i], this);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Verifica se achou a tag aktion, caso sim, cria um novo objeto aktion.
     * Verifica se encontrou a tag classname e seus atributos e seta os valores conforme a necessidade.
     * Verifica se encontrou a tag parameter e seus atributos e seta os valores conforme a necessidade.
     * Verifica se encontrou a tag mapping e faz o controle de conteúdo. 
     */
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String tag, Attributes atts){

        if (tag.equals(NO_AKTION)){
            aktionTemp = new Aktion();
        }   

        if (tag.equals(NO_CLASSNAME)){
            for (int i = 0; i < atts.getLength(); i++) {
                if (atts.getQName(i).equals(ATT_CLASSNAME_TYPE) && (atts.getValue(i).equals("M") || atts.getValue(i).equals("V"))){
                    classTemp = new Classname();
                    typeClassName = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (tag.equals(NO_MAPPING)){
            mappingOpen  = true;
            mappingExist = true;
        }

        if (tag.equals(NO_PARAMETER)){
            parameterTemp = new Parameter();
            parameterOpen = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < atts.getLength(); j++) {
                if (atts.getQName(j).equalsIgnoreCase("name")){
                    parameterTemp.addListAtts(atts.getValue(j));
                }
            }
        }
    }


    /** 
     * Indica que o parser achou o fim de uma tag/elemento.
     * Este evento fornece o nome do elemento, e tambÃ©m pode
     * fornecer as informaÃ§Ãµes sobre o namespace.
     */
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String tag){

        //Se encontrou o final da tag aktion, adiciona o conteúdo da aktionTemp
        if (tag.equals(NO_AKTION)){
            if (typeClassName){
                aktion.add(aktionTemp);
                typeClassName = false;
                aktionOpen    = false;
            }
        }

        //senão, seta os valores conforme a necessidade
        else if (tag.equals(NO_CLASSNAME) && (!aktionOpen)){
            if (typeClassName){
                for (int i = 0; i < classTemp.listTag.size(); i++) {
                    if(!classTemp.getListTag(i).equals(tempValue)){
                        aktionTemp.addClassname(classTemp);
                        classTemp.addListTag(tempValue.toString().trim());
                        aktionOpen = true;
                    }
                }
            }


        } else if (tag.equals(NO_PARAMETER)){
            if (parameterOpen && !mappingExist){
                aktionTemp.addParameter(parameterTemp);
            }
            parameterOpen = false;
            mappingExist  = false;

        } else if (tag.equals(NO_MAPPING)){
            mappingOpen = false;
        }

        //Limpa o conteúdo da tempValue
        tempValue.delete(0, tempValue.length());
    }

    /**
     * Indica que o parser achou algum texto.
     */
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) {
        tempValue.append(ch, start, length);
    }

    /**
     * Imprime os valores obetidos
     */
    public void imprimeAktion(){
        for (int i=0; i<aktion.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(aktion.get(i));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            SaxWFReader reader = new SaxWFReader();
            reader.parse();

            System.out.println("VALORES OBTIDOS");
            reader.imprimeAktion();

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            System.out.println("Parser não configurado adequadamete: ERRO: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            System.out.println("Erro ao efetuar o parse do arquivo selecionado: ERRO: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Probelmas de Leitura do arquivo: ERRO: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Classe `Classname`:

```java
public class Classname {

    List<String> listTag  = new ArrayList<String>();


    public String getListTag(int i) {
        return listTag.get(i);
    }
    public void addListTag(String tag) {
        this.listTag.add(tag);
    }

    public String toString(){
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < listTag.size(); i++) {
            sb.append("classname " + getListTag(i));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Classe `Parameter`:

```java
public class Parameter {

    List<String> listAtts = new ArrayList<String>();

    public String getListAtts(int i) {
        return listAtts.get(i);
    }
    public void addListAtts(String tag) {
        this.listAtts.add(tag);
    }

    public String toString(){
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int j = 0; j < listAtts.size(); j++) {
            sb.append("parameter name=" + getListAtts(j));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Classe `Aktion`:

```java
public class Aktion {

    private ArrayList<Parameter> parameter = new ArrayList<Parameter>();
    private ArrayList<Classname> classname = new ArrayList<Classname>();

    public Parameter getParameter(int i) {
        return parameter.get(i);
    }
    public void addParameter(Parameter parameter) {
        this.parameter.add(parameter);
    }

    public Classname getClassname(int i) {
        return classname.get(i);
    }
    public void addClassname(Classname classname) {
        this.classname.add(classname);
    }

    public String toString(){
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < classname.size(); i++) {
            if (getClassname(i) != null){
                sb.append(classname.get(i));
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < parameter.size(); i++) {
            if (getClassname(i) != null && getParameter(i) != null){
                sb.append("\n" + parameter.get(i));
            }else
                sb.append(parameter.get(i));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```